# What to do when fetching/creating a cache thats empty? Memcached, Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, caching, memcached

So right now users have a list of items that changes, but not too often, so I decided to keep it in a cache like so:

```
  #Fetch the cache
  def self.fetch_cache(user)
    Rails.cache.fetch(user.items, :expires_in => 15.minutes) do
      user.items.order("created_at ASC").all
    end    
  end
```

This works if the user has items. The problem is, if the user doesn't have any items (because they're a new user or something) and the cache will return an error.

How should I be using this to make it work for users with nothing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using a really weird cache key there (the first argument to `Rails.cache.fetch`). You're supposed to be passing a string that identifies the cache entry but you're passing in an association.

Rails is probably helpfully calling `to_s` on `user.items` in order to turn it into a string that but that's not a useful cache key as you're going to have to load the user's items in order to compute the cache key to get the users' items from the cache!

Something like `"user_#{user.id}_items"` would be a far better cache key.